# Quotient rules?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find an equation of the line tangent to the graph of $$f(x)= \frac{2x^2}{3x-1}$$ at the point $x=1$.

I feel like this should be relatively easy. I know how to take the derivative of the top portion, but how do I take the derivative of a linear line? Is it just $3$?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Yes, the derivative of $3x-1$ is $3$..

Comment: Not of the top portion ! You need the derivative of $f(x)$. What is the linear line ?

Answer (score 1):

By the quotient rule:

If $f(x) = \dfrac{g(x)}{h(x)}$, then $$f'(x) = \dfrac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{(h(x))^2}$$

In your case, that means:

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{(2x^2)'(3x-1) - 2x^2(3x-1)'}{(3x-1)^2}$$

Recall that for $(3x - 1) = 3x^1 - 1$, so that by the "power rule" $(3x^1-1)' = 1\cdot 3x^0 - 0 = 3$.

---

To find the slope $m$ of your desired tangent line when $x = 1$, evaluate $m = f'(1)$. Now we just need the coordinates of a point on the line: knowing that we are interested in the equation of the line  tangent to the curve *at* $x = 1$, evaluate the original function $f(x)$ at $x=1$ to find the $y$-coordinate, to obtain the point $(1, f(1)) = (1, 1)$, which necessarily lies on both the tangent line and the function.

Finally, use slope $m$ and the point $(1, 1)$ to construct the the point-slope equation of the line tangent at $(1, 1)$:  $$(y - 1) = m(x - 1)$$